# Call jQuery code when window resizes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that I would like to call everytime the browser resizes. That way it can keep up with the new element dimensions and size them accordingly.

Is it possible to wrap this in some kind of wrapper to be called when the browser resizes?

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".prodbox").each(function(i){
        i++;
        $rowNumber = (Math.ceil(i/4) - 1)*4;
        $maxHeight = Math.max(
                $(".prodbox").eq($rowNumber).height(),
                $(".prodbox").eq($rowNumber+1).height(),
                $(".prodbox").eq($rowNumber+2).height(),
                $(".prodbox").eq($rowNumber+3).height()
            );
        $(this).height($maxHeight);
    });
});
```

Comment: A sidenote: caching `$('.prodbox')` won't hurt here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html

```
width: <span id="widthId"></span> px<br />
height: <span id="heightId"></span> px
```

**jQuery solution**

```
$('#heightId').html($(window).height());
$('#widthId').html($(window).width());
$(window).on('resize', function(){
$('#heightId').html($(window).height());
$('#widthId').html($(window).width());
});
```

Unable to give u my css

```
    @media screen and (max-height: 400px)  
    {


     #heightId 
    {
    color: #fff;

     }

    }
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) 
{
    #widthId {
        color: #0f0;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) 
{
    body {
        background-color: Black;
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap it with the following:

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  // ..
}).resize(); // Execute on load
```

Updated jQuery:

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
    $(".prodbox").each(function(i){
        i++;
        $rowNumber = (Math.ceil(i/4) - 1)*4;
        $maxHeight = Math.max(
                $(".prodbox").eq($rowNumber).height(),
                $(".prodbox").eq($rowNumber+1).height(),
                $(".prodbox").eq($rowNumber+2).height(),
                $(".prodbox").eq($rowNumber+3).height()
            );
        $(this).height($maxHeight);
    });
}).resize();
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/MldSF1Z.png Hmm, didn't work. What I'm trying to do is have this resize for mobile devices when I get down to mobile width / heights. For instance, once I hit iPad width / heights, the product names are running behind the pricing plate area. I'm trying to make the .prodbox class resize when the browser resizes so this won't happen. Maybe that's the wrong approach?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [responsive CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Comment: Right, but I'm trying to do it dynamically based on the product's name. I don't want to have a blank line where I don't need one. Some products have 2-3 lines of name. What I'm looking to do with the JS is find the largest product name in a 4 product line, then based on that I set the height of them all to be the same. That way, everything looks as though it's aligned very well.

Otherwise, one product would be 3 lines, another 1 line, another 2 lines, it would look hella sloppy. This way at least everything is in line with eachother.

Comment: @user2433689 I didn't include `$(document).ready(..)`, I assume you still put that in, right? It works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/85G8D/), I wonder if a viewport should be set? Otherwise the JS in the function simply didn't work in the first place.

Comment: Try using table cells - easiest way to keep a row of boxes the same height.

Answer (score 0):

> [Bind an event handler to the "resize" JavaScript event](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".prodbox")
        .resize(resizeHnadler)
        .each(resizeHnadler)
})

var resizeHnadler = function(i){
    i++;
    $rowNumber = (Math.ceil(i/4) - 1)*4;
    $maxHeight = Math.max(
        $(".prodbox").eq($rowNumber).height(),
        $(".prodbox").eq($rowNumber+1).height(),
        $(".prodbox").eq($rowNumber+2).height(),
        $(".prodbox").eq($rowNumber+3).height()
    );
    $(this).height($maxHeight);
}
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/MldSF1Z.png Hmm, didn't work. What I'm trying to do is have this resize for mobile devices when I get down to mobile width / heights. For instance, once I hit iPad width / heights, the product names are running behind the pricing plate area. I'm trying to make the .prodbox class resize when the browser resizes so this won't happen. Maybe that's the wrong approach?

Comment: Maybe post something on jsfiddle so that we can take a closer look. I was just illustrating how resize() would be called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

**.resize() - Bind an event handler to the "resize"**

```
$(window ).resize(function() {
 $(".prodbox").each(function(i){
        i++;
        $rowNumber = (Math.ceil(i/4) - 1)*4;
        $maxHeight = Math.max(
                $(".prodbox").eq($rowNumber).height(),
                $(".prodbox").eq($rowNumber+1).height(),
                $(".prodbox").eq($rowNumber+2).height(),
                $(".prodbox").eq($rowNumber+3).height()
            );
        $(this).height($maxHeight);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hi There, Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).resize(function(){
         $(".prodbox").each(function(i){
           i++;
           $rowNumber = (Math.ceil(i/4) - 1)*4;
             $maxHeight = Math.max(
            $(".prodbox").eq($rowNumber).height(),
            $(".prodbox").eq($rowNumber+1).height(),
            $(".prodbox").eq($rowNumber+2).height(),
            $(".prodbox").eq($rowNumber+3).height()
        );
       $(this).height($maxHeight);
    });
});
});
```

> Thanks,